# Does this edit makes the post worse or it add's up some quality to it?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I edited this post:- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20257213 and it was rejected.

One user approved it so there are chances that my edit proves useful but there were other two rejection on it and it got finally rejected. The problem goes as the post has content like **I have a problem** and some code formatting issue so I fixed it. This type of text is clearly not needed and so I trimmed it. Without that code formatting edit the code would be no sense as it was lacking one closure bracket.

The rejected message was: **This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.**

To my knowledge to what I have edited in this post there is nothing that my edit harms the readability and the changes can't be said superfluous because it fixed the formatting and trimmed extra content. I have seen many 2k+ users editing post in which only a word is changed, but they have the privilege and no one cares to see the revisions of low quality posts.

My question:- Does my edit is superfluous or is it harming the readability in any sense? And if yes than what is here I can improve myself in editing further posts or something I need to keep in mind while editing. Because at last the quality of SO questions and answers matters.

Comment: I assume this is a culture thing, but adding a dash after a colon looks strange to me. I've never seen it in any book/document that I've read.

Comment: ohkay that's fine but other factors cant be neglected. @honk

Comment: It's totally superfluous, you added hyphens after colons which is now dated and rarely used in most countries, you've added a missing closing brace to the code but didn't think to indent the contents of the `ListResponse<O>` class, and while you've removed *"I have a problem."* and fixed a couple of capitalisation issues they don't make the question any easier to read than it already is. As said by yivi if you had 2k rep this wouldn't be an issue but this is not worth entering the review queue. I would've rejected it in a heartbeat

Comment: Please don't change `:` to `:-`, this is wrong. The correct punctuation is `:`. You should actually *remove* incorrect punctuation such as `:-` when editing.

Comment: So if I would have 2k rep than adding that hyphen would be fine. Than it would not be termed superfluous. I think if this the mentality than a new queue should be introduced to review edits made by 2k+ users and that privilege should be given to only 10k+ users. @NickA

Comment: @parthu_panther `adding that hyphen would be fine` No, because this is not correct English punctuation... :)

Comment: @Moritz I don't have any problem in learning and I can understand what your point is.

Comment: And please remove the code-formatting from "Retrofit 2.0" - this is not code....

Answer (score 9):

It is usually better to wait until you have more than 2k to perform this kind of edit. To clog the review queue with superfluous edits takes away review time from more significative suggested edits.

Both removing *"I'm having a problem"* and writing *API* in uppercase are fine as they are, but considering the whole post, they do not add much to it. And more importantly, since the post is closed, by editing you are sending it to the reopen review queue, and you haven't made any changes that change that situation.

So with this edit you could be taking time in two review queues: the suggested edits queue (to approve an edit that doesn't do much to improve the question), and if approved and the reopen queue, where it would lose it would have reviewers would have to chose "leave closed", since your edit didn't do anything to make the question not a duplicate.

With closed questions, it is better to only suggest edits when they push the post over the closable threshold.

Comment: It's worth noting the edit was suggested prior to the question being closed, which wasn't in OPs control, although it may have had an effect on the result of the review

Comment: @NickA It would have pushed to the reopen queue if the suggested edit was approved after the post was closed. Although you are aright than parthu could not necessarily know that the post was going the be closed afterwards.

Comment: The closure thing is acceptable and makes sense but, the edit was suggested prior to the closure. And so if it was not closed than what would have be the probability of its acceptance? @yivi

Comment: @parthu_panther Maybe slightly higher, it depends on the reviewers, whether or not they checked if the question was open/closed and whether or not they cared, it's not really possible to say. There's every possibility that the same suggested edit could even be accepted (although I am **not** saying you should try again)

Comment: @parthu_panther I do not think there is anything wrong per-se with that suggested edit, although it was very close to be superfluous (and that hyphen is weird). Personally, I would have skipped it so someone else would approve it. I think it is better to use your suggested edits in a meaningful way, since they need to go through the review queue. If you are going to take time from the reviewers, make it worth it. Once you get to 2k, no need to show such restraint.

Comment: "To clog the review queue" [citation-needed] The queue hasn't been clogged in a long time.